# Is it ungrammatical to substitute 'incorrect' with 'wrong' in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

I dislike people that use 'literally' wrong.

Comment: It is obvious that you need an adverb

Comment: I forgot about our quality standards, so I answered. But usually you are expected to show some effort on your part. For example, do **you** think it is wrong or right and why? This is for future reference.

Comment: Depends on what dialect the person speaks. *Incorrect* can be a 'flat adverb' (which means an adverb that doesn't end in *-ly*) in some dialects  or just to some speakers. Standard English probably wants it to be *incorrectly*.

Answer (score 3):

You are using "wrong" and "incorrect" as modifiers for "use" and so they need to be adverbs.

> I dislike people that use *something* wrongly.
>   I dislike people that use *something* incorrectly.

would be standard ways of using the adverbs.

Comment: You are correct. However, "wrong" is often used in speech instead of "wrongly" (which seems a little stilted to my ears), but "incorrect" is (practically?) never used instead of "incorrectly". Hence "incorrect" is wrong-er [sorry!] than "wrong".

Comment: If you use "wrong", though correct, it may introduce an ambiguity. For example, "use a spoon wrong" is unambiguous, but in "use something wrong" is the something inappropriate, or is the use incorrect?  I was erring on the side of generality to avoid individual cases.

Answer (score 2):

> I dislike people that use 'literally' wrong.

This is ok! The word *wrong* acts an an adverb, so the sentence is grammatical.

> I dislike people that use 'literally' incorrect.

This is not ok! It is grammatically incorrect because *incorrect* behaves as an adjective. We need an adverb here. It should be written as

> I dislike people that use 'literally' **incorrectly**.